# GlassFish Server: Administrator port is occupied by null

Tags: java, netbeans, glassfish

I tried to start `glassfish` server via the Netbeans IDE but it showed this error:

```
Could not start GlassFish Server: Administrator port is occupied by null
C:\Users\Ateeq Khaliq\Documents\NetBeansProjects\WebApplication1\nbproject\build-impl.xml:1045: Deployment error: Could not start GlassFish Server: Administrator port is occupied by null
See the server log for details.
BUILD FAILED (total time: 2 seconds)
```

I have changed the port also to 9999 in C:\Users\Ateeq Khaliq\GlassFish_Server\glassfish\domains\domain1\config file.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Change this

[image]

the solution is change the host configuration

Answer (score 1):

netstat -aon | find ":4848" | find "LISTENING"

Kill the process that is using your Administrator port

Comment: Please check out the [formatting help page](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) to improve your formatting.

Answer (score 0):

Its seem to be a [Bug](https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=237477) in Netbeans
if you have alraidy found a solution please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem and the way I solved it was to delete the glassfish, tomcat7 and tomcat 8 servers from my IDE. I then deleted their folders on my hard disk and reinstalled the glassfish alone. Everything worked fine after that.

Answer (score 0):

If Netbeans is blocked by Firewall this happens. Make sure your Antivirus firewall is not blocking NetBeans. Grant NetBeans full access to act as a server (This is also asked when you start NetBeans).

Then you should be able to start your server through NetBeans

Answer (score 0):

remove glassfish server from Netbeans and added another one click Tools-servers
select your server and click remove servers and click add servers change the domain name and change port from 8080 to 8090 as you like. restart Netbeans

Answer (score 0):

It has a really simple solution, just restart the Java process in your machine and you should be good to go..